# Stack two videos side and side but play one after another. Show thumbnail when not playing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos, that i want to concatenate side by side but second one should play after the first one. If the video is not playing, thumbnail should be shown

Below is the example that i want to achieve using ffmpeg https://twitter.com/sunmor2901/status/1520024861619658752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -i -filter_complex "[1:v]tpad=start_mode=clone:start_duration=5[rvideo];[1:a]adelay=5s:all=true[raudio];[0][rvideo]hstack[vout];[0:a][raudio]amix[aout]" -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp4`

You have to manually set the delay of the second (right) video from the 5 seconds in the example.

Comment: Thanks above works if both videos are of same resolution. How can i concatenate two videos of two different resolutions along with above effect.    Also, I would like to add small  text below the video describing what the video is all about (as seen in sample video link in question) ..  Is all this possible in one command?